# What will be the sub-category for a short-term Training/Internship visa for Germany on the VFS website?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I wanted to book an appointment for a Schengen visa for Germany with VFS in India. The visa sub-category is Training/Internship. However, on the VFS website, the only options for Schengen visa are airport transit, business visa, cultural, seaman, short-term medical treatment, sports, tourists, visit to family and friends. Out of these, which sub-category should I choose for a short-term Training/Internship visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I applied under `Business visa` subcategory, mentioned about training/internship in cover-letter. And got the visa.